# How is it possible that the spell didn't work fully?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

At the end of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* (first movie from the series)

> All city including Jacob is obliviated by the rain.

The main characters are sad about it, so it seems they believe it really worked. But at the beginning of the *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald* (second movie) we find out that

> the spell didn't work on Jacob and he still remembers what happened and he still is in love with Queenie

**How is that possible? Is it possible that more people would also not be enchanted?**

My thought:

> Did Queenie managed that? She would be willing to probably.

Comment: I'm 99% positive this is a duplicate... let me see if I can find it.

Comment: It's the plot. The plot requires Jacob to remember.

Comment: Implication at the end of the first movie (kiss, bakery scene): Love + Queenie being quite capable in mind magic on an intuitive level = she (unconsciously) counters effects of the obliviation. I thought this was quite obvious even without the second film.